# How to call a parent and assign some css in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML and I am trying to get the parent of in img element and assign a css only to that one but I really don't understand why I can't, or why it doesn't work.

Here is my HTML

```
                    <a id="spoon">
                        <span data-picture="" data-alt="spoon">
                            <span data-src="img/rect-img/spoon-small-left.png" class="spoon" style="width:61px;height:104px"></span>
                            <span data-src="img/rect-img/spoon-medium-left.png" data-media="(min-width: 768px)" class="spoon" style="width:98px;height:167px;"></span>
                            <span data-src="img/rect-img/spoon-large-medium-left.png" data-media="(min-width: 1140px)" class="spoon" style="width:145px; height:248px;"><img alt="spoon" src="img/rect-img/spoon-large-medium-left.png"></span>
                            <span data-src="img/rect-img/spoon-large-left.png" data-media="(min-width: 2048px)" class="spoon" style="width:260px; height:446px;"></span>


                        </span>                                                     
                    </a>
```

And my JQuery is this:

```
$('a#spoon img').parent().css('display', 'block');
```

I tried this as well but it doesn't word either.

```
$('a#spoon span.spoon:has(img)').css('border','1px solid white');
```

Comment: if it's not a direct parent use .parents("selector")

Comment: Probably because your `img` is in the `<noscript>` section of your page

Comment: its the immediate parent that I want to get

Comment: @Samy the img is created using the picturefill.js depending on the size of the device.

Comment: @Monica it's still not accessible to jQuery as it is in the `noscript` section. What parent exactly are you trying to access?

Comment: @Monica, your first selector should work: `$('a#spoon img').parent().css('display', 'block');` You are probably running it too soon?

Comment: @Sergio my js is the last running. you can check my code [here](http://labs.lesevades.com/recipe-book)

Comment: @Monica, was is the behaviour you are looking for? I see the knife and fork, looks goot to me

Comment: @Sergio What I am trying to do is to center that menu, and I want the '.main-nav' to get the current size so that by percentage I can move ti to the left. But so far nothing seems to be working

Comment: @Monica, see you here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42287/fast-chat

Answer (score 0):

Based on you markup you can use `.closest()`

```
$('#spoon img').closest('span').css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: this doesn't even work "$('a#spoon').width()" keeps returning cero

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the images were not loaded, so I couldn't get the width of any of the images. So I had to use this

```
    $( window ).load(function() {
    var navigation = $('.main-nav').width();
    var totalLeft = winWidth/2 - navigation/2;
    $('.main-nav').css('left', totalLeft);
});
```

to be able to make the calculations I needed to position my image.